# Spyder TKinter buttons require multiple clicks before execution

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, spyder

I'm new to Python and currently working on a password generator program using the Spyder IDE with TKinter. I'm encountering an issue where, especially after the first run, clicking any button in my code doesn't execute on the first click. I often need to click multiple times before the button executes. I'm unsure if it's related to my IDE settings and would appreciate any assistance. This issue is not specific to the code below but occurs in all programs where I've used TKinter. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randint, choice, shuffle
import pyperclip
import json

# ---------------------------- PASSWORD GENERATOR -------------------------------

def generate_password():
    print("generating password")
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

    password_letters = [choice(letters) for _ in range(randint(8, 10))]
    password_numbers = [choice(numbers) for _ in range(randint(2, 4))]
    password_symbols = [choice(symbols) for _ in range(randint(2, 4))]

    password_list = password_letters + password_numbers + password_symbols

    shuffle(password_list)

    password = "".join(password_list)

    password_box.insert(0, password)

    pyperclip.copy(password)

# ---------------------------- SAVE PASSWORD -------------------------------

def save():
    print("saving")
    website = website_box.get()
    username = username_box.get()
    password = password_box.get()
    new_data = {
        website: {
            "username": username,
            "password": password,
        }
    }

    if len(website) == 0 or len(password) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="oops", message="Please fill in the empty fields")
    else:
        try:
            with open("data.json", "r") as data_file:  # Read the file first
                # Reading old data
                data = json.load(data_file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            with open("data.json", "w") as data_file:  # Then write the file
                # Writing the updated data and saving it
                json.dump(new_data, data_file, indent=4)
        else:
            # Updating old data with the new data
            data.update(new_data)

            with open("data.json", "w") as data_file:
                json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)
        finally:
            website_box.delete(0, END)  # Removes previous entry in 'website box' when the user clicks 'Add' button
            password_box.delete(0, END)  # Removes previous entry in 'password box' when the user clicks 'Add' button

# ---------------------------- SEARCH FUNCTION -------------------------------

def search():
    print("searching")
    searching_for = website_box.get()
    try:
        with open("data.json", "r") as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Error", message="No data file found")
    else:
        if searching_for in data:
            username = data[searching_for]["username"]
            password = data[searching_for]["password"]
            messagebox.showinfo(title=searching_for, message=f"Username: {username}\nPassword: {password}")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Error", message=f"No details for {searching_for} exists")

# ---------------------------- UI SETUP -------------------------------

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
lock_image = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=lock_image)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)

# ------------------------ LABELS ------------------------

website_label = Label(text="Website:")
website_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

username_label = Label(text="Email/Username:")
username_label.grid(column=0, row=2)

password_label = Label(text="Password:")
password_label.grid(column=0, row=3)

# ------------------------ ENTRY BOXES ------------------------

website_box = Entry(width=20)
website_box.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=1)
website_box.focus()  # Launches with cursor inside the website entry box to allow typing

username_box = Entry(width=35)
username_box.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2)
username_box.insert(0, "johnsmith@hotmail.com")  # Prepopulate the username box with a username

password_box = Entry(width=20)
password_box.grid(column=1, row=3, columnspan=1)

# ------------------------ BUTTONS ------------------------

generate_button = Button(text="Generate Password", width=11, command=generate_password)
generate_button.grid(column=2, row=3)

add_button = Button(text="Add", width=33, command=save)
add_button.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2)

search_button = Button(text="Search", width=11, command=search)
search_button.grid(column=2, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does it mean that it works fine when not using Spyder? If yes, then you should raise the question to Spyder development team instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried it with PyCharm and it indeed works fine with PyCharm. Sorry for being a total newbie but how do I raise the question to the Spyder team?

Comment: You can [create an issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) in the project repository. But first, check your IDE settings, particularly how tkinter works with different graphics backend settings.